# Same absolute path works for \input but does not work for \include, why?

Tags: input, include, multiple-files

If I use the command "\input{filepath}" then the file is perfectly printed in "main.tex". If I only change the command to "\include{filepath}" I get the following error:

> I can't write on file `filepath.**aux**'.

With the AUX extension, even though is a .tex file.

Ex post: I have a Mac with MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\input` only needs read permission, but `\include` writes an aux file for each included file, so it needs write permission.

Comment: Thanks David. Is there a way I can use \include? That is, to give write permission?

Comment: David, I apologize for asking basic questions. What is that allows write access? The file is in the Desktop, and I also tried to put it in a folder but it does not work.

Comment: I see. But if I put the file in the same folder of the main text, and hence just write \include{filename}, then everything works. Mystery or not?

Comment: @TSant that's expected. If you did not have write access to that folder you wouldn't be able to edit your main file either.

Comment: If you using absolute pathes they are special security settings preventing you to write.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oops yes good call, that's  perhaps a more likely possibility.